# Question of Venn Diagrams and Subsets on a Book

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In this [book](https://www.utstat.toronto.edu/mikevans/jeffrosenthal/book.pdf), Section 1.2.1 on page 7 introduce Sets and a diagram on page 8

[image]

Here, I am confused about the hightlighted area.
[image]

Is there an error here?
Should

> A ∩ Bc = {s : s ∈ A and s ∈ B}

be

> A ∩ Bc = {s : s ∈ A and s ∈ Bc}

Isn't `A ∩ Bc` the waning cresent(moon phase term) of `A`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are correct. It should say

$$A\cap B^c = \{s : s \in A \text{ and } s \in B^c \}$$

or, equivalently,

$$A\cap B^c = \{s : s \in A \text{ and } s \notin B \}.$$

(Note that the equivalence of these definitions depends on the fact that $B^c$ is defined with respect to a larger set $S$ *that contains $A$.*)

Comment: As an author, I'd venture a guess that this came from copying and pasting and forgetting to completely modify the lines which produced the two equations.